# Query PFObjects into swift array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

This is my initialisation of the array:

```
var restaurantsArray = [String]()
```

Here is the query function:

```
func loadRestaurants(){
    let fetchRestaurantsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Restaurants")
    fetchRestaurantsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            //after successfull fetch
            print("b")
            if let fetchedRestaurants = objects{
                print("c")

                for fetchedRestaurant in fetchedRestaurants{
                    print("a")
                    self.restaurantsArray.append(fetchedRestaurant.objectForKey("Name") as! String)
                    print(fetchedRestaurant.objectForKey("Name") as! String)
                }
            }

        }else{
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the code in the for-loop is never called. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Just a suspicion, but did you check if you do get actually some Restaurants back? Maybe there's no error so you pass both `if` statements but you don't enter the `for` if there are no Restaurants.

Comment: yes I'm double checking my query now

Answer (score 0):

Since `objects` is declared as optional `[PFObject]?` the proper optional binding syntax is just

```
if let fetchedRestaurants = objects {
```

and `fetchedRestaurant in fetchedRestaurant` is pretty weird.

```
for fetchedRestaurant in fetchedRestaurants {
```

Comment: I edited my code to the above but the code still won't enter the for-loop

Comment: You have still the expression with the two exclamation marks. Both are not needed as well as the casting. The right side of `if let` must be optional. And it's not recommended to use the same variable name `objects = objects`

Comment: when I add "?" to the right side of `if let` , Xcode tells me to delete it. Also, the code is entering the if-statements but not the for-loop

Comment: Look at my answer, there is neither `?` nor `!`. `objects` is optional by declaration (method signature). If the body of the for loop is not executed `objects` is empty.